# ClumpFinding Optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to optimize a python function to compute a ClumpFinding in Bioinformatics.

I have written the function but I am getting a `TypeError`:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'
```

I have tried recasting to 'int'

```
def ClumpFinding(genome, k, L, t):
    FrequentPatterns = []
    index = 0
    CLump = {}
    for i in range(0, 4**k):
        CLump[i] = 0
    Text = genome[0:L+1]
    FrequencyArray = Computing_Frequencies(Text, k) 
    for i in range(4**k):
        Value = int(FrequencyArray[i])
        if Value > t: 
            CLump[i] = 1
        elif Value == t:
            CLump[i] = 1
    for i in range(1, len(genome) - L):
        FirstPattern = genome[i-1:(i-1)+k]
        index = PatternToNumber(FirstPattern)
        FrequencyArray[index] -= 1
        LastPattern = (genome[i + L - k:(i + L - k)+k])   
        index = PatternToNumber(LastPattern)
        FrequencyArray[index] += 1
        Value = int(FrequencyArray[index])
        if Value > t: 
            CLump[index] = 1
        elif Value == t:
            CLump[index] = 1
    for i in range(4**k):
        if CLump(i) == 1:
            Pattern = NumberToPattern(i, k)
            FrequentPatterns.append(Pattern)
    return (' '.join(map(str, FrequentPatterns)))
```

Here is the error message:

```
(Lines 19 and 23)
FrequencyArray[index] -= -1 and FrequencyArray[index] += 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

Frequency array is a string array and hence it can't be subtracted or added with an int.

Do something like

```
FrequencyArray = [int(i) for i in FrequencyArray]
```

after

```
FrequencyArray = Computing_Frequencies(Text, k)
```

to convert it to an int array.